# How to declare a variable/function from libraries in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, variables, three.js, libraries

As I know from JAVA, the keyword **import** is used to declare a library in a Class.

Im looking something similar for Javascript due to multiple ReferenceError massages i get from several libraries.

---

I tried declaring the libraries in the HTML but I think its not working okay:

```
 HTML:
//webgazer.js Library
<script type="text/js" src="libraries/WebGazer/webgazer.js"></script>
//Three.js
<script type="text/javascript" src="libraries/Three.js/Three.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libraries/Three.js/three.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libraries/Three.js/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<!-- MY SCRIPT -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/setupPage.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/3DCanvas.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/faceFeatures.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/modals.js"></script>


 I tried all the ways i found online on how to import JS libraries but no luck

import * as webgazer from 'libraries/WebGazer/webgazer.js';
import * as lib from 'libraries/WebGazer/webgazer.js';
import * from 'libraries/WebGazer/webgazer.js';
import * from 'libraries/WebGazer/webgazer.js';
import {webgazer} from './libraries/WebGazer/webgazer.js'; 
import {webgazer} from 'webgazer';
import {webgazer} from 'webgazer.js';
import function name(parameters) {webgazer} from 'libraries/WebGazer/webgazer.js';
var webgezer = require ( 'libraries/WebGazer/webgazer.js');
```

Example 1 (Three.js) - works & has error:

[image]

Example 2(webgazer.js) - not working & has error:

[image]

Comment: How are you building your Javascript for the browser?

Comment: @AndyRay, i updated my question for you.

Comment: If you are using plain scripts, not any module format, then you don't have to import anything - the variables are just available in the global scope. How does the library you want to use export them? You should be able to find a description how to use the library in their documentation.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi. Where should I look to understand the whole concept of the import-export-require?

Comment: @LoizosVasileiou For ESM, it would use `import`, `export`
For CommonJS and others, you would use `module.exports` most of the time.
Obviously your scripts would need to leverage this syntax to namespace them into the way you want.

These pieces of code that leverage this syntax is found on `npm`
To learn the whole concept, you can probably google something like require vs import

Comment: I know this is a bit old, but if you are getting the error from eslint here's how to remove the error. put  /* global THREE */ at the top of your script. From https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring search for "To specify globals using a comment"